# How to get element from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
var fkTableArr1d = new Array();

fkTableArr1d = _.map(fkTableArr2d, function(list, iterator, context) {          
      return { "id " : list[0], "label " : list[1] };
    });
```

`fkTableArr1d` becomes:
`[Object, Object, Object]`
1 object is a `Object {id : "5", label : "fuel"}`

Now how I'm supposed to get ID of an element with label `fuel`?

Below one doesn't work:

```
console.log(fkTableArr1d['fuel']);
```

Comment: Overdriven Fall, you are using the value `'fuel'` as the index instead of finding which array object has this value. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for [`findWhere()`](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere):

> Looks through the list and returns the first value that matches all of
>   the key-value pairs listed in properties.

```
_.findWhere(fkTableArr1d, {label : "fuel"});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/38qUE/1/

Comment: it works, I had error in my array (I've created it by `"id" : list[0], "label"  : list[1]` instead of `id : list[0], label  : list[1]`)

Comment: Using string literals (the ones with quotes) vs "raw" identifiers should make no difference here.

Comment: somehow it did, because with string literals it didn't recognize `.id`, `.label`

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = 0;
if(fkTableArr1d.label = 'fuel') id = fkTableArr1d.id;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hQbx/)

Answer (score 0):

use any the following code snippets:

### snippet1:

```
fkTableArr1d =[{id : "5", label : "fuel1"}, {id : "6", label : "fuel"}, {id : "4", label : "fuel2"}];
for(x in fkTableArr1d)
    if(fkTableArr1d[x].label == 'fuel')
        alert(fkTableArr1d[x]['id']);//syntax1 for accessing object member. alerts '6'.
```

**[fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/Gh5v8/)**

### snippet2:

```
fkTableArr1d =[{id : "5", label : "fuel1"}, {id : "6", label : "fuel"}, {id : "4", label : "fuel2"}];
for(x in fkTableArr1d)
    if(fkTableArr1d[x].label == 'fuel')
        alert(fkTableArr1d[x].id);//syntax2 for accessing object member. alerts '6'.
```

**[fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/p5QBt/)**

Comment: I get `undefined` when I try `for(x in fkTableArr1d) console.log(fkTableArr1d[x].id);` or `fkTableArr1d[x]['id']`

Comment: You need `var` before `x`. Right now you are defining it as global.

Comment: @OverdrivenFall Please check the fiddle I have given. Perfectly working in the fiddle.

Comment: @Pavlo, Please check the fiddle. `var` is needed only when to declare `x` locally. But there is no such restriction here.

Comment: @Pavlo I completely agree with you. But didnt think of it too much to demonstrate this.